# Using stat_binhex() with ggpairs()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I would like to use the `stat_binhex()` statistic from `ggplot2` with the `ggpairs()` function (`GGally` R package).  For example, I would like to use `stat_binhex()` in [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpeJ0.png) instead of `geom_point()`. Is that possible?

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
library(GGally)
library(hexbin)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20*3), ncol=3))
p <- ggpairs(df, lower="blank")
seq <- 1:ncol(df)
for (x in seq)
  for (y in seq) 
    if (y>x) 
      p <- putPlot(p, ggplot(df, aes_string(x=names(df)[x],y=names(df)[y])) + stat_binhex(bins=4), y,x)
p
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of `GGally` (2.1.2) this is much easier than it used to be: doesn't require any low-level hacking, and can more easily be combined with other aspects of `ggpairs` customization.

```r
ggally_hexbin <- function (data, mapping, ...)  {
    p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) + geom_hex(...)
    p
}
ggpairs(df, 
    ## use 'ggally_hexbin' for continuous × continuous plots
    lower = list(continuous = "hexbin", 
    ## use default plots for all other variable types
    combo = "facethist", discrete = "facetbar", na =  "na"))
```

[image]

Comment: This helped me plot a massive data.frame quickly after trying to plot a scatter, which seemed like it would need several hours to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot believe that this is still not part of the `GGally`'s `ggpair()`'s customisation.

Building on [lukeA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872644), let us convert that to a function:

Setup requirements and define the function:

```
require(ggplot2)[enter image description here][1]
require(GGally)
require(hexbin)


ggpairs_hex <- function(df, hexbins = 10) {
  # REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872133/using-stat-binhex-with-ggpairs
  p <- ggpairs(df, lower="blank")
  seq <- 1:ncol(df)
  for (x in seq)
    for (y in seq) 
      if (y>x) 
        p <- putPlot(p, ggplot(df, aes_string(x=names(df)[x],y=names(df)[y])) + stat_binhex(bins = hexbins), y,x)
  
  return(p)
}
```

Generate some data:

```
require(MASS)

# data generation from:
# https://predictivehacks.com/how-to-generate-correlated-data-in-r/
set.seed(312)
# create the variance covariance matrix
sigma<-rbind(c(1,-0.8,-0.7), c(-0.8,1, 0.9), c(-0.7,0.9,1))
# create the mean vector
mu<-c(10, 5, 2) 
# generate the multivariate normal distribution
df<-as.data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n=10000, mu=mu, Sigma=sigma))
```

Test the function:

```
ggpairs_hex(df, hexbins = 5)
ggpairs_hex(df, hexbins = 10)
ggpairs_hex(df, hexbins = 20)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]